# i need help understanding a concept. javascript onkeydown

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I made a game in HTML and javascript. as I'm a beginner, I don't know how to make the object go 'smooth'. what I mean by that is I made an object, and on "onkey" press, it will move. the problem is it will get stuck for 1s after pressing the key, and then continue.
I searched for an answer and found what I've been looking for (but I don't understand the code and how it works, as it includes $... and stuff like that, which I'm not familiar with).

```
    function moveLeft()
        {
            var movementy=30;
            var x = document.getElementById("ball").offsetLeft;
            x = x - movementy;
            document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + "px";
        }

        function moveRight()
        {
            var movementy = 30;
            var x = document.getElementById("ball").offsetLeft;
            x = x + movementy;
            document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + "px";
        }
function ballmoveup()
        {

            var movement = 3;
            var y = document.getElementById("ball").offsetTop;
            y = y - movement;
            document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + "px";
            window.onkeydown = function (event)
            {
                if ((event.keyCode == 39))
                {
                    moveRight();
                }
                if ((event.keyCode == 37))
                {
                    moveLeft();
                }
            }

            if (y<=20)
            {
                GameEnd();
            }
```

I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it properly while understanding what I'm doing (means no $).
also, the ballmoveup() is inside an interval, of ("ballmoveup",10);

Comment: I don't see a `$` anywhere.

Comment: As a general comment, I would *strongly* suggest understanding at least the basics of jQuery (i.e. `$`) - at least for scripts you intend to run on browsers.  Developing without it would be crippling yourself unnecessarily.

Comment: `$` is generally a JQuery keyword that tends to represent the `this` object. It sounds like you found some examples in JQuery. I suggest looking into JQuery and potentially integrating it into your code if you are trying to use a snippet from elsewhere, or just convert the JQuery into JavaScript. For the latter, you could (and should) include the code you don't understand here. Also, you should probably include your full code so it can be reproduced. As it is, there isn't much to help with.

Comment: you can apply a css [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) on the `id="ball"` element.. then add some code to reset your event loop on key press so it happens on press and not on next loop iteration

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle  I would definitely disagree with that. It doesnt take long to learn how to manipulate DOM with native javascript and if you form an understanding of how it works at a lower level then you will know what is happening, even with a library like jQuery.

Comment: my general problem is with:
`window.onkeydown = function (event)
            {
                if ((event.keyCode == 39))
                {
                    moveRight();
                }
                if ((event.keyCode == 37))
                {
                    moveLeft();
                }
            }`

Answer (score 1):

One big problem is that you are setting an event listener inside **ballmoveup** and the function itself is called every 10 ms inside an interval which means that you are adding a new eventlistener every 10 ms.

You should move your eventlistener function out of **ballmoveup**.

In case you want to have animations (the easy way) you can use this:

```
#ball {
  transition: left 0.4s;
}
```

Also it's better to have the state of your game as variables out of functions:

```
var left = 0;
```

so you won't have to call this everytime (you just modify the variable and set the left)

```
document.getElementById("ball").offsetLeft;
```

Comment: I moved the eventlistener out of the function, as you suggested (I forgot that it works 'generally' when out of function)
I couldn't incorporate the transition into my code, but that's fine, as i dont mind if it moves like 100px every time, i just need the button to move it at constant pace, and not   a tick, 1s wait, and then lots of ticks
will try your last advice in the future tho.